# mlpack train weighted DecisionTree using sample frequency

Tags: c++, decision-tree, mlpack

Following the example from the [official documentation](https://www.mlpack.org/doc/mlpack-git/doxygen/cv.html#cvbasic_ex_2), I am at this point in training a DecisionTree classifier:

```
arma::rowvec weights = arma::randu<arma::mat>(1, labels.size());
size_t numClasses = 2;

KFoldCV<DecisionTree<>, Accuracy> cv2(5, data, labels, numClasses, weights);
size_t minimumLeafSize = 12;
double weightedDecisionTreeAccuracy = cv2.Evaluate(minimumLeafSize);
```

My question: does DecisionTree work well if the samples from the 2 classes are not evenly distributed?
How should I modify my code to take into account that in the training set there is a 75% samples from class 1 which narrowly distribute around a single value, while the remaining 25% are from class 2 and are quite sparse?